# Set java heap size in machine with dynamic memory size

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Tomcat in virtual machine with dynamic memory size. Admin said that memory size incrised when it needed for system. 
But when i try to set `-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m` in setenv.sh i get an error:

```
Tomcat could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

Now Tomcat starts with `-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m` settings.
Its possible to set 2Gb start memory size in my case?

OS: Ubuntu 13.04 64bit

Comment: Can you please tell us what OS your VM is running?

Comment: In VM running Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: 32bit or 64bit? Please elaborate your question a little bit more.

Comment: Im add information in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 2GB of memory available in you system for the the tomcat process to start, I guess then you can use -Xms2048m. -Xms2048 means, your JVM will need this much memory for initial allocation and if it cannot allocate, you might get the exception.